# Is there a way to append string to the front of a ruby Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

So right now I have a method that normally just takes a string

```
def stub_url(endpoint = "/", auth = nil)
  url = "https://#{auth}test.example.com#{endpoint}"
  stub_request(:get, url).to_return(:status => 200)
end
```

But I would also like to accept a Regular Expression as an endpoint, so I tried doing a something like this

```
def stub_url(endpoint = "/", auth = nil)
  if endpoint.is_a?(Regexp)
    # this is where I'm stuck
    url = 
    # url should be regex
  else
    url = "https://#{auth}test.example.com#{endpoint}"
    # url should be string
  end
  # stub_request can take string or Regexp
  stub_request(:get, url).to_return(:status => 200)
end
```

For example:

`stub_url(/\/pirates.*/)`

Matches:

```
"https://test.example.com/pirates"
"https://test.example.com/pirates?some%20parameters"
```

Doesn't Match:

```
"/pirates"
"https://test.example.compirates"
"https://test.example.com/pirate"
```

Is there a way to append a Regexp onto a string?

Comment: good call, I will add them now

Comment: I still don't get it. `stub_url('/pancakes')` just appends `'/pancakes'` to the URL but `stub_url(/pancakes?/)` would do what?

Comment: It would create a regex that would match the same url I guess.  But the reason I'm trying it is so that I can accept extra parameters (using `/\/pancakes.*/`)

Comment: Perhaps you should be building the URI using [URI from the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) instead of using string wrangling then. Maybe. I still don't know what `url` would be if you called, say, `stud_url(/x(yz)?/)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found to do it was something like this:

```
def stub_url(endpoint = "/", auth = nil)
  if endpoint.is_a?(Regexp)
    url = Regexp.new(Regexp.new("https://#{auth}test.example.com").source + endpoint.source)
    # But I could make it a little simpler like below
    # url = Regexp.new(/https:\/\/#{auth}test.example.com/ + endpoint.source)
  else
    url = "https://#{auth}test.example.com#{endpoint}"
  end
  stub_request(:get, url).to_return(:status => 200)
end
```

This method works by getting the regular expression of the string.  Prepending the regex source of that to the regex source of the passed in regex.  And finally getting the regex of that.

If you find a better way, let me know

Answer (score 1):

```
def stub_url(endpoint = "/", auth = nil)
  url = "https://#{auth}test.example.com"
  if endpoint.is_a? Regexp
    url = /#{Regexp.escape(url)}#{endpoint.source}/
  else
    url = "https://#{auth}test.example.com/#{endpoint}"
  end
  return url
  #stub_request(:get, url).to_return(:status => 200)
end

stub_url(/\/pirates.*/).source # => "https://test\\.example\\.com/pirates.*"
stub_url("pirates")  # => "https://test.example.com/pirates"
```

### Note

I have removed stub_request to show what you should expect, though I have a feeling you are doing something wrongly

Comment: I didn't mean in the literal sense, but in the sense of matching that string followed by the regex

Comment: I think what I wanted was still unclear, I updated it a lot more